# Importing a lot of form components in page with Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a component with a rather big menu, and for each menu item I have a different form to show, there will be at least 100 different forms, expected to be a few hundreds. Now the questions is it ok to import all this form components ? Is there a different way ?

And another thing related to this, I have a variable containing useful information for all sub-components, is it a good idea to provide it using dependency injection, or should it be in inserted in all sub-components via @Input ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the router to load the form components you can use [AsyncRoute](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/AsyncRoute-class.html) for lazy loading.

`@Input` binding is convenient if you want to pass values to a direct child component or directive.
If you need to pass to a component that isn't a direct child, a service still works while a binding doesn't.

I'd say, use what's more convenient in your situation.

With components added by the router or DynamicComponentLoader a service is usually more convenient.

You can just create a lookup table (an object where you register all types with a name

```
{ MyComponent1: MyComponent1, MyComponent1: MyComponent2, ...}
```

and then just look the types up using the string name. Angular is working on pre-rendering, I guess it will be more efficient to load all components at once this way.

Comment: The forms are to deep intro the structure to use routing for them, don't think it's a good idea. With DynamicComponentLoader I will still need to import, but the biggest problem is that I will have to create a very big ngSwitch statement to tell DCL what type to load, unless there is something to convert a string to a type...

Comment: You can just create a lookup table (an object where you register all types with a name `{ MyComponent1: MyComponent1, MyComponent1: MyComponent2, ...}. And then just look the types up using the string name. Angular is working on pre-rendering, I guess it will be more efficient to load all components at once this way.

Comment: If you can add this to your answer, and thanks as always for your help, you're always there for angular2 related questions :)

Comment: Thanks! I try. Lots of interesting things to learn from good questions :)